# Why can't I access the properties of a sequelize object with keys in the form '[Op.or]'?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I am building a sequelize query. While doing some debugging I was surprised to find that I couldn't access the properties of my options.where object, but that console.log still returned the expected object structure.
My question is (1) why does this occur and (2) how do I get around the problem to access the properties?

My code looks like this:

```js
findOptions.where = {
      [Op.or]: [
        {
          id: {
            [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`,
          },
        },
        {
          serialNumber: {
            [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`,
          },
        },
    ]};
```

This uses, so far as I can tell, standard sequelize syntax. However, `_.isEmpty(findOptions.where)` evaluates to `true`, `findOptions.where[0]` evaluates to `unknown`, `JSON.stringify(findOptions.where)` returns `{}` and `Object.keys(findOptions.where)` returns an empty array. Despite this, `console.log` returns the expected result:

```js
{
  [Symbol(or)]: [
    { id: [Object] },
    { serialNumber: [Object] }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the log shows, `Op.or` is a [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol). Those are typically ignored as properties, at least by [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) or `for … in` loops - you'd need to check [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols) to test whether there are any symbol-keyed properties in the object.

You access the property using `findOptions.where[Op.or]`, not `findOptions.where[0]` - it's not an array.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `findOptions.where` is an object which has one property. The key of that property is the result of evaluating the expression `Op.or`.

When you `console.log` the whole object you can see that it is a [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol).

> ```
> findOptions.where[0]
> ```

`0` is not the same as `Op.or`, so you're trying to access a property that doesn't exist.

> ```
> JSON.stringify(findOptions.where)…
> ```

See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) which says:

> All Symbol-keyed properties will be completely ignored, even when using the replacer parameter.

---

If you want to access the property then you have to use its key:

```
 findOptions.where[Op.or]
```